# using string from char() in `";displayname;"` in plot

Tags: plot, octave, legend

**update:** 
I've isolated the issue of why the `legend()` wasn't working. The question regarding that: 
[Does `legend ( )` require implicit variables which get lost in different scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73001779/does-legend-require-implicit-variables-which-get-lost-in-different-scope)

---

- I am trying to call a variable in the format  `";displayname;"` property for a `legend` in `plot` [15.2.1 2-D plots](https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html), but I can't find any documentation regarding it.
- I can't get the `legend()` to work probably due to the way my actual code is structured. And I am unable to debug as the Octave GUI is not working on my pc & I don't know how to debug on the Octave CLI.
- so, defining legend within the `plot()` somehow is the only resort as it seems to me.

Isolated test codes:

```matlab
cur = char ( ["hi";"he";"le"] )

% Legend works in isolation, but not in my actual program

loglog ( 3*[1:10].^3 )
legend ( cur(1,:) )
```

```matlab
% Tries:

% Prints verbatim
loglog ( 3*[1:10].^3, ";cur(1,:);" )

% Throws syntax error
loglog ( 3*[1:10].^3, ";"cur(1,:)";" )

% Throws error "__plt2vv__: vector lengths must match"
loglog ( 3*[1:10].^3, (";" + cur(1,:) + ";") )
```

The second & third tries were based on [this post on MATLAB central](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/154272-input-a-variable-into-a-plot-title#answer_376203)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf()`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/sprintf.html) to explicitly build strings. Use `%s` to denote a string variable to add: `sprintf(";%s;", cur(1, :))`.

Using array concatenation you could do `[";", cur(1, :), ";"]`. Octave doesn't do string concatenation using the `+` operator as far as I know.

Comment: (umh, what was the additional personal tip you gave in the comment ) it was something like "I ..."

Comment: I find explicitly building strings using `sprintf()` easier and especially more readable than trying to concoct one using array concatenation.

Comment: @user8395964 if you wanted string concatenation specifically, rather than formatting more generally, then there's also the `strcat` function which performs concatenation. e.g. `strcat( ';', cur(1,:) ,';' )`