# gca is limited to a single scope

Tags: scope, octave, legend

S/w : Octave v7.1.0

#### Background:

- I picked the code example given at 15.2.4 [docs.octave/.../Multiple-Plots](https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Multiple-Plots-on-One-Page.html) and modified it to use multiple figures

- As can be seen, this code separates the implementation in 2 different `for` loops - say 2 different blocks (I don't know about octave, 'am just using from terminology of C lang)
- The above separation causes issue when using `legend()` in 2nd block (error thrown attached below)
- So, it means that some variable which `legend()` uses to assign legends is not available in 2nd block i.e. is lost to the previous block, while other variables explicitly initiated like `hax` etc are not lost

#### Questions:

- Is my diagnosis regarding the issue (scopes and lost of value) right?
- What implicit variables/values are required by `legend()`? 15.2.3 [docs.octave/.../Plot-Annotations](https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Plot-Annotations.html#XREFlegend) says `gca` but how to pass that across scopes? Manual of legend for reference: * 15.3.3.4 [docs.octave/.../Legend-Properties](https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Legend-Properties.html)

- Why does the example on the site separates the logic in 2 blocks when it's prone to such bugs? Is there any upside to this? And which one would be the recommendation in general case scenario?
- I was not able to find this error by debugging or normal thinking. The point regarding scope didn't come even after so long as all the other variables like hax, or figure are still working. So, what are the ways with which I could have actually found this error mechanically? Like in C the gcc's `-W` flags shows pretty good technical descriptions of the issue.

#### Materials:

**The error shown with buggy code:**

```
error: legend: no valid object to label
error: called from
    legend>parse_opts at line 770 column 7
    legend at line 210 column 8
    isolated_code at line 20 column 9
```

**The buggy code:**
/!\ Beware, don't blindly copy paste, as it may result in lost of workspace figures/variables due to `close all; clear all;` commands in first line

```matlab
close all; clear all;

legend_n = char ( ["1"; "2"; "3"] );

x = 1:3;
y = rand (6,3);

for i_loop = 1:2
    figure();
    hax(i_loop) = newplot ();
    hold (hax(i_loop), "on");
endfor
for i_loop = 1:2
    for i_plot = 1:3
        iy = (i_loop - 1)*3 + i_plot;
        plot (hax(i_loop), x,y(iy,:) ...
            # , sprintf( "x-;%s;" , legend_n(i_plot, :) )
            , "x-", "displayname", legend_n(i_plot,:)
            );
        legend ();
        # legend (hax(i_loop), i_plot);
    endfor
endfor
```

**Working code:**
Merge the 2 blocks of `for` together, i.e. remove their separating `end for \n for`.
`diff -u` of buggy and working code gives:

```
@@ -9,8 +9,6 @@
     figure();
     hax(i_loop) = newplot ();
     hold (hax(i_loop), "on");
-endfor
-for i_loop = 1:2
     for i_plot = 1:3
         iy = (i_loop - 1)*3 + i_plot;
         plot (hax(i_loop), x,y(iy,:) ...
```

Full copy of working code as requested in comments:

```matlab
close all; clear all;

legend_n = char ( ["1"; "2"; "3"] );

x = 1:3;
y = rand (6,3);

for i_loop = 1:2
    figure();
    hax(i_loop) = newplot ();
    hold (hax(i_loop), "on");
    for i_plot = 1:3
        iy = (i_loop - 1)*3 + i_plot;
        plot (hax(i_loop), x,y(iy,:) ...
            # , sprintf( "x-;%s;" , legend_n(i_plot, :) )
            , "x-", "displayname", legend_n(i_plot,:)
            );
        legend ();
        # legend (hax(i_loop), i_plot);
    endfor
endfor
```

Comment: Writing `legend ();` in the 4th line from below makes no sense. However, what you need is `legend(hax(i_loop),"show");` between the two `endfor`s instead.

Comment: the suggested code works. but why the `legend()` or the `legend (hax(i_loop), i_plot);` doesnt work, i mean, what do they do then?

also, can you post this as an answer, so that i can accept it as answer and such?

Comment: and also, why does it work in the "working code" above?

Comment: Please write executable "working code"

Comment: @SardarUsama done, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `legend`, `plot` and other axis related functions do their function in current axis of current figure unless you tell them otherwise. When you create figure windows before plotting, the last axis in your last figure is your current axis. So if you want to do plotting or show legend in any of the previous figure/axis then you should use the relevant figure/axis handle to do so.
2. You should call `legend` when you are done plotting on an axis unless you are making an animation in which you want to see the legend updating as the plot entries change. Otherwise you will unnecessarily be calling `legend` multiple times.

Your first code after making the above mentioned fixes:

```
legend_n = ["1"; "2"; "3"];  
%No need to call char in above line as you already have a char array

x = 1:3;
y = rand (6,3);

for i_loop = 1:2
    figure();
    hax(i_loop) = newplot ();
    hold (hax(i_loop), "on");
endfor
for i_loop = 1:2
    for i_plot = 1:3
        iy = (i_loop - 1)*3 + i_plot;
        plot (hax(i_loop), x,y(iy,:) ...
            , "x-", "displayname", legend_n(i_plot,:));
    endfor
    legend(hax(i_loop));  %calling legend with the relevant axis handle
endfor
```

In your second code, `legend` is being called in the current axis/figure and hence you get no error. But you should call it after the end of your inner `for` loop.